# Changing NSError's localized description language

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm using NSError's property `localizedDescription` to output AFNetworking requests errors. Regardless of the device selected language `localizedDescription` is always on English.

Is it possible to get the `localized` description on other languages supported by the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFNetworking does not provide any localisations, you only get English. But there is nothing stopping you from getting the AFNetworking strings translated yourself into the languages that your app supports.

In the context of most apps, low-level error messages of this kind aren't user-friendly and it's a better idea to provide your own error message.

Answer (score 1):

From an issue opened on [github](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2396)

> All user-facing strings can be localized using the AFNetworking localization table. Only the base (English) localization is provided by default.